# Does Android UI have a change detection mechanism?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm reading Angular, and found the change detection mechanism the biggest obstacle so far. React and Vue also have some form of change detection. The problem of detecting changes in information, and then reflecting such changes to the display seems to be universal and UI framework-agnostic, yet I can't found anything like that for Android.

Why is that? Is there a shift in paradigm/aspect of the problem that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI paradigm used by Angular, React, and Vue is called [reactive programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming). This is an alternative to a more traditional [imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) paradigm, where it is up to developers to manually update the UI state.

The Android framework `View` system is an imperative style of development. Being the same framework since the original Android version, it was built before Angular, AngularJS, React, and Vue even existed and hence, uses a very different style.

[Jetpack Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose) is a new UI toolkit under development that **does** use a reactive programming style where updating the state automatically updates the associated UI.